# How to validate Google ID token, issue with C#

Tags: c#, google-signin

After I retrieve the ID token in my Android project, I need to verify the integrity of the token, and I did, using `Google.Apis.Auth` lib for C#. But the problem is, anybody could send a valid Google token to my endpoint easily, so I need to validate if this token was generated from my app and not some random.

So I validate the token by:

```
 var validPayload = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(model.IdToken);
```

And I receive the User info. But how can I verify if this token came from my app's ID?

I found an example where it passes the Audience "ID Client". But what is this ID Client?

[image]

Comment: Your question depicts one this, but your code depicts another, So does this exception actually have anything to do with the problem?